# okhttp loggin interceptor in multipart

Tags: android, forms, multipartform-data, okhttp

I am trying to upload an image using okHTTP multi part into a server. the server does not accept my request. my problem is that I cannot see the parts of my multi part in the logging intercepter, so I cannot debug. here is the code that I use and the reulting log cat and the desired payload. any help is appreciated.

```
            RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("uploaded_file", filename, RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG, sourceFile))
                .addFormDataPart("flowChunkNumber", "1")
                .addFormDataPart("flowCurrentChunkSize", String.valueOf(sourceFile.getTotalSpace()))
                .addFormDataPart("flowChunkSize", "1048576")
                .addFormDataPart("flowIdentifier", "4731-images1jpeg")
                .addFormDataPart("flowFilename", "images (1).jpeg")
                .addFormDataPart("flowFilename", "images (1).jpeg")
                .addFormDataPart("flowRelativePath", "images (1).jpeg")
                .addFormDataPart("flowTotalChunks", "1")
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .addHeader("cookie", ******* )
                .url(URL_UPLOAD_IMAGE)
                .post(requestBody)
                .build();

        HttpLoggingInterceptor logInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient
                .Builder()
                .addNetworkInterceptor(logInterceptor)
                .build();


        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

and this is what I see in the log cat when I use an interceptor

> D/OkHttp: --> POST https://www.appido.ir/api/profile/avatar http/1.1
>
> D/OkHttp: Content-Type: multipart/form-data;
>   boundary=a8028055-3a30-4942-916b-af56935e8b32
>
> D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 14097
>   D/OkHttp: cookie: ************************
>   Domain=.appido.ir; expires=Tue, 23-Aug-2016 13:31:11 GMT; Path=/
>
> D/OkHttp: Host: www.appido.ir
>
> D/OkHttp: Connection: Keep-Alive
>
> D/OkHttp: Accept-Encoding: gzip
>
> D/OkHttp: User-Agent: okhttp/3.4.1
>
> D/OkHttp:
>   h������gTRC���������lumi���� 07-25 07:47:49.163
>   7776-8509/com.androidbuts.uploadimage D/OkHttp: |������meas���� 07-25
>   07:47:49.163 7776-8509/com.androidbuts.uploadimage D/OkHttp:
>   �������$bkpt���� 07-25 07:47:49.163
>   7776-8509/com.androidbuts.uploadimage D/OkHttp: �������rXYZ����
>
> **and this gibberish goes on for many lines**
>
> D/OkHttp: --> END POST (14097-byte body)

How can I see a meaningful log cat? I want to acihieve this :

> ------WebKitFormBoundaryJDdhM3Si8enJZABA Content-Disposition: form-data; name="flowChunkNumber"
>
> 1 
>   ------WebKitFormBoundaryJDdhM3Si8enJZABA Content-Disposition: form-data; name="flowChunkSize"
>
> 1048576 
>   ------WebKitFormBoundaryJDdhM3Si8enJZABA Content-Disposition: form-data; name="flowCurrentChunkSize"
>
> 23016
>   ------WebKitFormBoundaryJDdhM3Si8enJZABA Content-Disposition: form-data; name="flowTotalSize"
>
> 23016
>   ------WebKitFormBoundaryJDdhM3Si8enJZABA Content-Disposition: form-data; name="flowIdentifier"
>
> 23016-60x60music2_smalljpg
>   ------WebKitFormBoundaryJDdhM3Si8enJZABA Content-Disposition: form-data; name="flowFilename"
>
> 60x60music2_small.jpg
>   ------WebKitFormBoundaryJDdhM3Si8enJZABA Content-Disposition: form-data; name="flowRelativePath"
>
> 60x60music2_small.jpg
>   ------WebKitFormBoundaryJDdhM3Si8enJZABA Content-Disposition: form-data; name="flowTotalChunks"
>
> 1
>   ------WebKitFormBoundaryJDdhM3Si8enJZABA Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="blob" Content-Type:
>   application/octet-stream
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryJDdhM3Si8enJZABA--

Comment: It’s printing the content of the PNG file?

Comment: @JesseWilson Thank you for your answer, I solved this issue.

Comment: Resolved here https://github.com/square/okhttp/pull/3833

Answer (score 6):

The way to see the contents of a Multipart upload from Okttp and Retrofit is to use Stetho, by Facebook, and add StethoInterceptor to the Okhttp logger

https://github.com/facebook/stetho

It puts the Android app's network requests in your dev machine's chrome inspector.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I ended up writing my own intercepter